# SharePoint Survey Custom View/Edit/Delete Permission for Custom Group

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, survey

I am creating a survey in SharePoint 2007 and would like the following setup:

1. Survey respondents can view/edit/delete only their own responses
2. A SharePoint group (composed of teams lead/managers) can view all responses but cannot edit/delete (unless their own survey response)
3. A SharePoint group (composed of team leads) can view/edit all responses to add notes to the response. The group members could intersect with group #2 members.

I have configured 1 above through a survey advanced settings. But I'm not sure if 2 and 3 are possible. I have tried the following:

1. Created a new permission level that allows editing/viewing of list item.
2. Create a new group and assign #1 permission level

Above doesn't seem to work. The survey response permission is getting overwritten by the survey setting allow users to view/edit/delete their own responses only.

Any advice?

Thanks.